# Multiples of entries for the same software name

Tags: i3, dmenu

For a while now I have been using i3 with dmenu over a xubuntu. One thing that keeps bugging me is that there are some apps for example on my install the "file manager", "vlc media player" and "xfce terminal" that have multiple entries in dmenu, indicated by an (2) in the name.
This is particularly frustrating for the file manager because there is about a 50/50 chance that it will actually open the file manager rather then the "file manager preferences" app and it isn't even consistent which opens which. Sometimes "file manager" opens the actual file manager, sometimes the preferences app and the same goes for the (2).
My question would be, is there a way to at least fix which opens which, or preferably change the name so there isn't multiple entries list on the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files that describe the items that dmenu shows are called desktop entries, and are located in the directories :

- /usr/share/applications/
- /usr/local/share/applications/
- ~/.local/share/applications/

There might be a duplicate file in one of those directories.

If it is in either the directories with local in their names, you can delete it

If it is in /usr/share/applications/, you’ll have to look at which packages possess the files that are doubled, and either

- remove those packages or
- override the name of the entries

If you chose to override the name of one of these entries, it is simple :

- first copy the .desktop file to ~/.local/share/applications
- then, *in that copy*, change the "Name=Application Name"  to what you desire

If you wish to know more about these files, you can read :
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries